# You're looking at us right now; what are we?

Tags: riddle, word

> You're looking at us right now.
>   Like atoms, we are indivisible.
>   We are the bane of a young child's existence.
>   However, we are not always seen together.

What are we?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Letters

You're looking at us right now.

> I'm reading

Like atoms, we are indivisible.

> Letters are a union of lines, taken alone they're not letters any more.

We are the bane of a young child's existence.

> Referred to the struggle of children while learning to write

However, we are not always seen together.

> There are a lot of cases where letters alone have meaning

Comment: @MatthewSmith I know what you mean. When I posted my first question on this stackexchange it was also answered within 10 minutes. Some of these people here are extremely fast in answering correctly, which took me by surprise on more than one occasion.

Comment: @MatthewSmith I think this is a side effect of the [many-eyes effect](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2947/the-many-eyes-effect)